# Remove the folder added to Project

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidently selected 'Add files to my project' and added my project file itself once again in my project. Now when I delete that added folder, then all the classes and folders previously present is shown as deleted. Now if I drag the file again, things are again fine.

How can I delete the folder that I added to my project without affecting other files/classes...?

Comment: What happens if you delete the file and to do **remove reference**?

Comment: removing reference worked @iPeter..Thanks..:)

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete the file and whe confirmation popup appears select **Remove Reference** instead of **Move to Trash**. Please check below screenshot for more reference.

[image]